# Notation for the vector space of functions with $k$ continuous derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, notation

I saw the following definition given at the mathworld web site:

> A function with $k$ continuous derivatives is called a $C^k$ function. In order to specify a $C^k$ function on a domain $X$, the notation $C^k(X)$ is used. The most common $C^k$ space is $C^0$, the space of continuous functions, whereas $C^1$ is the space of continuously differentiable functions.

My problem with the definition is that $C^k$ is presented as a function and also as a space. Can anybody help to explain this to me?

Comment: This is just a linguistic mishap at mathworld.com. In the phrase "a $ C^k$ function", $ C^k$ is used as an adjective. The space of $ C^k$ (adjective) functions with domain $X$ is written as $ C^k(X)$ (noun). Thus we do not use $ C^k(X)$  "to specify a $ C^k$ function", but rather to denote the space of all such functions (on $X$). One might reformulate as: "In order to express that $f$ is a $ C^k$ function on a domain $X$, the notation $f\in C^k(X)$ is used", but that is unnecessarily clumsy compared to saying that $ C^k(X)$ is the space of ...

Answer (score 1):

$C^k$ means space of functions on some domain, if written $C^k(X)$ then your domain is $X$, but if only $C^k$ that means domain is obvious from context. Some element $f \in$ $C^k$ means a $k$ continuous function. $C^k$ always means space

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.please see my next question on C^1