# Definition of $C^1, $the vector space of continuously differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, functions, definition

I asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1054047/147263) on clarification of   the symbol $C^k$. It was confirmed to me that $C^k$ is actually a space of functions. Now my next question in the definition is on $C^0$ and $C^1$.

$C^0$ is ok to me as a space of continuous but it beat my imagination how $C^1$ is defined **as a space of continuously differentiable functions**. Shouldn't $C^1$ just mean the space of functions with at least first derivative? To me from the way it is defined  at mathworld web site, $k=0$ or $k=1$. Thus, $C^k$ is just twice continuously differentiable! Please let somebody clarify.

Comment: $C^k$ is the space of at least $k$ times differentiable functions such that the $k$-th derivative is continuous.

Comment: What do you mean by "that mathword definition"?

Comment: It seems you did not see my first question. Any, "that mathword definition" means the definition I saw given on mathWorld web site. I'm sorry about the wrong spelling of mathworld.

Answer (score 4):

$C^1$ means space of those function whose first derivative along with itself is continuous (it may have several other derivatives but they do not have to be continuous) on whatever domain you are working in.

Comment: Of course, if it has "several other derivatives" then they must all be continuous, with the possible exception of the highest one.